# Fixed background video makes other fixed elements clip

Tags: html, css, video, background, fixed

Good day to you all!

I have some issues. My site got fixed menu on scroll, practically the same as seen in https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp
It worked fine until I decided to put a video as background right underneath the body.

Now, when I scroll up or down it makes my fixed navigation jump/clip for a millisecond. What is causing this and how I can fix it? As I said the transition is smooth if I have an image as body's background.

Here is my styling for the video:

```
display: none;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
min-width: 100%;
height: auto;
z-index: -100;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow, your question as it, has not necessary information, please read [ask] to understand what is it expected. For instance you need to provide a [mcve] for you that would be stripped down example of the html code with the css to help people reproduce. Please [edit] the question to add this information.

Comment: Impossible to answer without more info or a URL. Do you have a URL we can check?

Comment: I will post url here after i upload it on live server, because i have found out that it is only present in firefox and cannot reproduce it in JS fiddle.